# A way to make simple digital potentiometer

Tags: audio, digital-potentiometer, digital-audio

I am making a project which has an audio application with a TDA amplifier.
To change the volume I have a potentiometer on the input of the amplifier so when you change its value the sound is higher or lower.

The problem is that I need to modify the volume without a potentiometer.
Searching I found that there are digital potentiometers which seem to be perfect for my project, but in my country they are quite expensive and are overkill because I only need 2 or 3 levels of volume.

My question is if I could make my own digital potentiometer only using some resistors and MOSFETs to add resistance in parallel,  decreasing the value of my input signal (making a voltage divider).

Is there some IC which has some MOSFETs built in and their logic solved so I only need to turn off and on each one?

Comment: I think it can be done.  Which TDA amplifier are you using?   What MOSFETs do you have available?   What is the nature of the source drive to the MOSFETS?  (i. e. is it 5V logic??)

Comment: Multiplying DAC usually do this job. They are wide-spread, old and cheap. Use reference input as audio input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1QyEi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [74HC4052](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4052.pdf) is suitable for +/-5V supplies maximum. You can use a manual potentiometer or two to find the values for the resistors. There are two channels in the 74HC4052 so you can do stereo with a single chip. There are 4 levels possible (binary selection 00/01/10/11 at A/B) so you can add one more level than I've shown.

Comment: Thats clever, i came across with an circuit witch have 2 npn transitors wich add resistors in paralelo  to the voltage divider. In simulations works preaty well. So i thinks there are quite forms to do the job.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Discrete MOSFETs aren't so simple in an application like this. Discrete MOSFETs can only block current one direction and pass current in both directions. MOSFETs are also controlled by the DIFFERENCE between the voltage at the gate and source pins. That means you can't just toss a MOSFET in the middle of a circuit and apply a ground referenced voltage to the gate and expect it to work properly if the source terminal is not also connected to ground. That means they are difficult to use in place of a potentiometer which might be sitting anywhere in a circuit. If one end of the pot needs to be to ground and current only flows in one direction through the pot, then it will be a lot more straightforward.

But you should just be able to use ICs called analog switches or analog multiplexers for your purpose.

Comment: Thats what you mentions (analog swiches) is exactly what i wanted. With that IC and some resistors i may do the job perfecly.
Thanks a lot, i didnt know that something like this exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Per your title and original message

> **Way to make a simple digital Potentiometer**
> Searching I found that there are digital potentiometers which seem to be perfect for my project, *but in my country they are quite expensive and are overkill* because **I only need 2 or 3 levels of volume**.

> My question is if I could **make my own digital potentiometer** only using some resistors and MOSFETs to add resistance in parallel…

My suggestion is based in the use of an **LDR** (light dependent **resistor**) - as the name implies, it is already a resistor and can be used as it is: its resistance varies from about 100R~1K (light) to 1M~5M (dark).
So you can obtain a resistance range varying quickly by 100:1 in a fraction of second, and an extended range up to 10000:1 if about 10 seconds are still acceptable.

There is even a name for such optocoupler device, being called **VACTROL** (Google this term).
It brings a bonus: as it is an *OptoCoupler* and provides *galvanic insulation*:  No concerns about ground loops or electrical shocks, with minimal interference, except from spurious pickup of light, if not properly encased.

There were a few audio applications in the past that used LDR(s) inside a control loop, either to create an automatic volume level control (AVL) or an audio compressor. In both cases, the LDR was part of a voltage divider, being illuminated by a LED, which brightness was dependent of the “volume” level at the output.
VACTROL in DIY versions are well described in several sites as in [ElectroSchematics here](https://www.electroschematics.com/vactrol-a-lazy-walk/)  including an *Arduino-based control* (with code) and is also seen in [Elliot’s Sound site here](https://sound-au.com/project200.htm)). From these sites, I created a collage to illustrate the concept of this kind of optocoupler:

[image]

Some additional reminders:

**Discretized or Digital volume levels**
If you just need 2/3/4 levels, you could make the “digital” steps in a discrete and analog way: using different resistors (or trimpots) to drive different LED currents. You don’t need a microcontroller for that discrete volume control, just a selector switch (rotary or sliding type) could do the trick, at least for the first volume tests.
For a real digital control, through Arduino, ESP, Raspberry Pi, etc, you don’t need several digital ports, as you can control LED brightness using an Analog Output or a sufficiently filtered PWM output.

**LED choices**:
For better brightness response by most LDRs, the LED color should be preferably chosen from green/yellow/orange/red variety (in that order). Milky acrylic is better than clear ones. White LED is not the best choice, because their phosphor ages long term light level is more affected. Diameter: 5mm is better than the smaller 3mm LED.

**LDR response time and dynamic range**:
LDR changes resistance faster from Dark to Light (High resistance to Low R) than the opposite.
This can be advantageous to provide a faster response to lower the volume, while the absolute maximum volume is achieved (at R > 5M) after a few seconds.
Minimum resistance of the LDR as low as 1K or even 0.1K can be achieved and will depend of the color and brightness produced by the LED, which is directly proportional to the driving current.
Maximum resistance can be as high as 5M, resulting in a resistance range that can be as high as 50000:1. This wide range can be limited using a high-value resistor in parallel - as 1M. This not only limits the resistance range to about 1000:1~10000:1, that would be acceptable in most applications, but also improves the perceived response time of the equivalent parallel circuit (LDR // 1M) under darkening conditions.

**LDR** is very affordable and quite easy to find in several countries.
If the words/concepts “**simple**”, “**inexpensive**” and “**easy to find**” are your main drivers, try this LDR-based optocoupler and let us know (ex.: in the comments) if it solved your needs.

Comment: Wow i never would thought that what you said. It is seems to be a very great idea and i will take in acount for future projects as well. For this time as i had a microcontroler (for other reasons),  i would use some circuit off the aboves that seems to be easy to calculate the values what i need. But really thanks for your answer i really aprecciate it :)